# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv

Tags: java, hadoop, classnotfoundexception

```
$ /usr/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/ImportTsv
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268) 
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Have you added the Hadoop library to the classpath, including at runtime? Are you using Maven or the like?

Comment: @hexafraction: I executed this command in the command line. No i didn't set any other parameter. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `/usr/bin/hbase classpath` and see if `hbase.jar` is on your classpath.

If it is **not** or the paths are wrong check your hbase configuration
`/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh` and make sure you do not have an environment `$HBASE_HOME` set to the incorrect location.